# How to encode a image in Python to Base64?

Tags: python

I have a RGB image in a numpy array of 3 dimensions.

I am currently using this

`base64.b64encode(img).decode('utf-8')`

But when I copy/paste the output to this website https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

It does not convert the image back.

But If I use this code:

```
import base64
with open("my_image.jpg", "rb") as img_file:
    my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
my_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
```

then it works. But my image is not saved in memory. And I don't want to save it, because it will decrease the speed of the program.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you need this base64 data _for_?

Comment: I am sending the image to another program, like an API

Comment: You can not base64 encode the image without reading it to memory. So `base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode('utf-8')` should be your solution. What is `img` in your first solution?

Comment: So should I first save the image like `cv2.imread('img.jpg',img)` then read it again?

Comment: If you want to see the output of the encoding process, type the following:

print image_64_encode

Comment: @TomHolland What does the other program expect? I don't think it expects raw uncompressed bytes packed in Base64.

Comment: It just expect a base64 string.

Comment: @TomHolland I don't understand. `img_file.read()` is reading the image file into memory. If your file is on the disk, you can use the line `base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode('utf-8')` to create the valid base64 representation of the image. You don't need cv2.

Comment: My file is not in the disk.

Comment: My file is in a variable. I am just telling the second solution work. But I need to write & read the image from memory

Comment: I have a variable named `img`. It contains the image.

Comment: If the first solution somehow work, I don't need to write & read the image again. Second solution is slower

Comment: Ok. Please add an input example of img to your question. Then it's clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can encode the RGB directly to jpg in memory and create a base64 encoding of this.

```
jpg_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
b64_string = base64.b64encode(jpg_img[1]).decode('utf-8')
```

Full example:

```
import cv2
import base64
img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
jpg_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
b64_string = base64.b64encode(jpg_img[1]).decode('utf-8')
```

The base 64 string should be decodable with https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: I knew it, not all heroes wear capes!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method :- RGB image base64 encode/decode**

```
import cStringIO
import PIL.Image

def encode_img(img_fn):
    with open(img_fn, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
        return data.encode("base64")

def decode_img(img_base64):
    decode_str = img_base64.decode("base64")
    file_like = cStringIO.StringIO(decode_str)
    img = PIL.Image.open(file_like)
    # rgb_img[c, r] is the pixel values.
    rgb_img = img.convert("RGB")
    return rgb_img
```

Comment: Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: I used this encode_img(img), where `img` = 3 dimensional rgb image

Comment: If you want to see the output of the encoding process, type the following:

print image_64_encode

Comment: The issue with this approach is more evident when you use `pathlib.Path(img_fn).read_text().encode("base64")` ... that is, the `encode` function depends on the object type. And here; the img_fn was nowhere read as as image.